# Unable to run my older react native project

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I am using an older project that was built on react-native version 0.63.4 which uses react-native-unimodules of version 0.10.1.

My installed versions:

Java: JDK8

Node: v14.21.3

Android SDK: Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 13
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.7762732, built on September 24, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64

When i am trying to run the command "react-native run-android" it throws me error
"CookieManagerModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method invalidate() in NativeModule"

why is this happening even after giving the specific version of react-native-unimodules and so on.

Also i was getting an kotlin issue but i have added an specific version of kotlin to resolve this. Why was the kotlin issue did not come earlier when i have used the same versions during development. Why only now i am getting the issue. Any help could be very helpful